# I can not read from database Visual basic

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, database-connection

```
Dim conStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\databaseVB\bakery.accdb"
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim Item(5) As String
        Dim key = TextBox1.Text

        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
       1>>>>> 'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE number = 3"
       2>>>>> cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE number = '" & key & "'"
        MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            Item(0) = reader("Number").ToString
            Item(1) = reader("FirstName").ToString
            Item(2) = reader("LastName").ToString
            Item(3) = reader("User").ToString
            Item(4) = reader("Pass").ToString
        End While
        MessageBox.Show(Item(1).ToString)
        conn.Close()
```

from 1>>> I can read Item in databaes
from 2>>> I can not read Item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a parameterized query string:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE number = @Number"
```

After this add your parameters.

```
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3;
//It is better to use .TryParse(), incase your users write non numerical values in the Textbox
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)TextBox1.Text;
```

Additionally you need to watch your data types. `3` is of type `int`, but `TextBox1.Text` is of type `string`. You need to parse the string to int in order for it to work.
This should do the trick and prevent ugly syntax juggling, while mixing strings and variables; And prevent you from SQL Injection attacks.